# Why CGImage size changed after resize with transparent background? And how to lower the memory cost?

Tags: ios, uiimageview, cgimage

I want to enlarge an image and fill the space with white color.

```swift
    func resizeImageWithTransparentBackground(originalImage: UIImage, targetSize: CGSize) -> UIImage? {

        let originalSize = originalImage.size
        let widthRatio = originalSize.width / targetSize.width
        let heightRatio = originalSize.height / targetSize.height

        var newSize = CGSizeZero
        //scale width or height
        if widthRatio - heightRatio >= 0.01 {
            newSize = CGSize(width: originalSize.width, height: originalSize.width)
        } else {
            newSize = CGSize(width: originalSize.height, height: originalSize.height)
        }
         
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, 0.0)
        UIColor.white.setFill()
        UIRectFill(CGRect(origin: .zero, size: newSize))
        
        // Center the original image
        let originX = (newSize.width - originalSize.width) / 2
        let originY = (newSize.height - originalSize.height) / 2
        let rect = CGRect(x: originX, y: originY, width: originalSize.width, height: originalSize.height)
        CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: 0)
        
        originalImage.draw(in: rect)
        
        let resizedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        
        return resizedImage
    }
```

But the CGImage size has changed:

[image]

Another side effect is that it cost high memory.
Why this happen and how can I solve this?

Thanks

Comment: By the way, I believe you can lose the `CGBitmapInfo` line, as that creates a value, but does nothing with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The size of the resulting image is enlarged by 3x3. You supplied 0.0 to the scale in `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` which means it will use scale factor or your device's main screen, which appears to be 3 in your case. If you want to keep the same size as the original image, set the scale parameter to 1.0.

If you want to keep the result image same size as the original image, you should get the scale from `originalImage` and supply that to the `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` function. Which @Rob pointed out is not necessarily 1.0.

The difference in alpha and byte ordering is because the original image doesn't have an alpha channel. By setting the opaque boolean flag to `false` the image context is created **with** an alpha channel. Since you are creating a full white background, it is safe to set the opaque flag to YES or true.

See the developer documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/1623912-uigraphicsbeginimagecontextwitho?language=objc

Comment: Good answer. But to be precise, do not want to use 1 for the scale, but rather the original image [`scale`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/1624110-scale), which is often `1`, but not always.

Comment: Thanks guy! You saved my life! And the memory cost is down either. The byte order is not changed after the opaque boolean flag  was set to **true** . And what should I do if the resolution of image is large and how to solve the memory problem?

Comment: @magic_9527 with the `CGBitmapContextCreate` function you also have control over the byte ordering (`UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` seems to be deprecated). Not sure what you mean with memory problem. Bitmaps can take a lot of memory, only keep them around if you need them.

Comment: @JackGoossen The memory problem means that when dealing with a large resolution image, the memory usage increases significantly. For example, in this question, when the image is enlarged by 3x3, the memory consumption is around 200MB, and when it is enlarged by 1x1, the memory usage is approximately 20MB. Enclosing an autoreleasepool is not helpful. What is the right way to deal with this?

Comment: @magic_9527 Large bitmaps can take up a lot of memory, that's a fact of life. That's why bitmap images stored on disk are usually compressed (e.g. PNG, JPEG). But you'll have to uncompress an image if you want to display or edit it. There are lots of strategies dealing with images and memory usage (scaling, compression, partially loading or tiling images, caching), but it all depends on what you want to do. If you have a specific question, I suggest you check for existing answers on stackoverflow or ask a new question.

Comment: @JackGoossen  Thanks guy. I have another question, could u plz help me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77443675/how-to-blend-image-with-mask-like-wwdc-segmentation-under-ios-13