# How to blend image with mask like WWDC segmentation under iOS 13?

Tags: ios, core-graphics, core-image

The link is https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10040/  and time is 12:20.

I have reached this on iOS 13

```swift
func blendImages(
      background: CIImage,
      mask: CIImage,
      isRedMask: Bool = true
    ) -> CIImage? {

        print("blendImages")
        print(foreground.extent.size)
        print(mask.extent.size)
      // scale mask
      let maskScaleX = foreground.extent.width / mask.extent.width
      let maskScaleY = foreground.extent.height / mask.extent.height
      let maskScaled = mask.transformed(by: __CGAffineTransformMake(maskScaleX, 0, 0, maskScaleY, 0, 0))



      let blendFilter = isRedMask ? CIFilter.blendWithRedMask() : CIFilter.blendWithMask()
      blendFilter.inputImage = foreground
      blendFilter.maskImage = maskScaled

      return blendFilter.outputImage
    }
```

foreground:

[image: 1]

mask(same ratio but not same size with foreground):

[image: 2]

result(The imageView bgcolor is blue):

[image: 3]

But how can I make this under iOS 13?

Thanks

Comment: The question is very unclear as it is. I assume you would like to implement this on iOS 12 or earlier? And the problem is that blendWithRedMask/blendWithMask is not available? If so can create the appropriate filters yourself (e.g. CIBlendWithMask). You will have to convert your red mask to a grayscale to support it.

Comment: @JackGoossen  Yes, I wanna make this on iOS 12 because **blendWithRedMask/blendWithMask** is available since iOS13. The mask's background is white and person is black, when blend with original image, only the person is transparent. I wanna clip or cover the person on an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To support iOS 12 and earlier, you can try this:

```
if let blendFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIBlendWithMask") {                
        blendFilter.setValue(foreground, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
        blendFilter.setValue(background, forKey: kCIInputBackgroundImageKey)
        blendFilter.setValue(maskScaled, forKey: kCIInputMaskImageKey)
                        
        return blendFilter.outputImage
}
```

You can instantiate Core Image filters by name. You can check the documentation below for an overview of filters.

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html

Comment: Really appreciate, bro!